# How to use count to to get the max value in SQL partition

Tags: sql-server, mysql, partitioning

I have a table including branches and items sold. I would like to check which item has the highest quantity sold in the store.
I have a table with hundreds of rows like this structure and need to use partition to order the count and see all the branches with their highest item sold. I tried so many times using code like the below but all fails, can anyone share some ideas on how to fix it? Thank you!!!

```
WITH TEMP AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION Branch, Item ORDER BY COUNT(Item) DESC) AS rn
FROM TABLE)
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, COUNT
FROM TEMP
WHERE rn = 1
```

Original Table:

| Branch | Item |
| --- | --- |
| NYC | Tea |
| Seattle | Mug |
| Boston | Coffee |
| Boston | Coffee |
| NYC | Tea |
| Seattle | Mug |
| Seattle | Tea |
| Boston | Coffee |
| NYC | Coffee |

```
SELECT BRANCH, ITEM, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY BRANCH, ITEM
```

Summarized Table:

| Branch | Item | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boston | Coffee | 3 |
| NYC | Coffee | 1 |
| NYC | Tea | 2 |
| Seattle | Tea | 1 |
| Seattle | Mug | 2 |

Expected output:

| Branch | Item | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | Tea | 2 |
| Boston | Coffee | 3 |
| Seattle | Mug | 2 |

Comment: Which product are you using? MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the surplus tag

Comment: I see NYC-tea in your output, did NYC-coffee transmogrify into TEA?

Answer (score 1):

If it is `MSSQL`, you have the syntax for the `PARTITION` wrong. Also you want to `PARTITION` by Branche, not by Item.

This gives the right result for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
   Branch VARCHAR(50),
   Item VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Temp
(
   Branch,
   Item
)
VALUES
(
   'NYC',
   'Tea'
),
(
   'Seattle',
   'Mug'
),
(
   'Boston',
   'Coffee'
),
(
   'Boston',
   'Coffee'
),
(
   'NYC',
   'Tea'
),
(
   'Seattle',
   'Mug'
),
(
   'Seattle',
   'Tea'
),
(
   'Boston',
   'Coffee'
),
(
   'NYC',
   'Coffee'
);

WITH CTE
AS (SELECT
             t.Branch,
             t.Item,
             COUNT(*) AS NumberOfItems,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Branch
                                ORDER BY COUNT(t.Item) DESC
                               ) Ranking
    FROM     #Temp AS t
    GROUP BY t.Branch,
             t.Item)
SELECT
         CTE.Branch,
         CTE.Item,
         CTE.NumberOfItems
FROM     CTE
WHERE    Ranking = 1
ORDER BY CTE.Branch;

DROP TABLE #Temp;
```

ps. Next time please provide the scripts to create DDL and testdata please.

Comment: Thank you so much!